# MS Access 2007 Error when changing from form view to design view

Tags: microsoft-access

I upgraded from MS Access 2003 to MS Access 2007 and I have a problem every time I change the view of my forms.

I have this one form and if I change it to design view an error message will pop-up. Here is the error message:

> The command or action 'Quit' isn't available now.
>
> You may be in a read-only database or an unconverted database from an
>   earlier version of "mydatabase".
>
> The type of object the action applies to isn't currently selected or
>   isn't in the active view.
>
> Use only those commands and macro actions that are currently available
>   for this database

Any idea what's the problem here and how will I go about this?

---

Additional information:

This happens only in one form. The name of the form is: Form_Main. Once I opened this database, the Form_Main opened into Form View. Now if I would like to change something in the Property Sheet, I right clicked on the Form View and select to Design View. And if I do this, this is when I got this error:

> The command or action 'Quit' isn't available now.
>
> You may be in a read-only database or an unconverted database from an
>   earlier version of "mydatabase".
>
> The type of object the action applies to isn't currently selected or
>   isn't in the active view.
>
> Use only those commands and macro actions that are currently available
>   for this database

Comment: Please clarify the context in which this happens. Are you changeing to design view through the UI, or in a macro or VBA code?

Comment: If someone else made or worked on this database it may contain old VBA code. Do you know how to edit code in Access VBA?

Comment: @subman: I have a very basic idea but not really good. What do you want me to do?